# How to post an object to an array in a json using Angular 6

Tags: json, angular

So I'm testing Angular 6 functionality out for fun to learn it and running a json-server to load a db.json to a localhost server to acquire via service calls which you can see here

```
{
 "customers": {
 "testingTitle": "Testing Title",
 "trainData":[
 {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Test Name 1",
  "email": "customer001@email.com",
  "tel": "0526252525"
 },
 {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Test Name 2",
  "email": "customer002@email.com",
  "tel": "0527252525"
 },
 {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Customer003",
  "email": "customer003@email.com",
  "tel": "0528252525"
 },
 {
  "id": 4,
  "name": "123",
  "email": "123",
  "tel": "123"
 }
 ]
}
```

I have a test.service.ts as followed which picks up the service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders, HttpParams} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

class Test {
  testingTitle: string;
  trainData:[
    {
      id : number;
      name: string;
      email: string;
      tel: string;
    }
    ];

}

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class TestService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public getAllTests(): Observable<Test[]>{
    const params = new HttpParams().set('_page', "*").set('_limit', "*");
    return this.http.get<Test[]>("http://localhost:3000/customers", {params}).pipe(map(res => res));
  }

  public postTests(object) {
    return this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/customers", object).subscribe(data => {console.log("POST Request is successful ", data);},error => {console.log("Error", error);});
  }
}
```

I have my test.ts which controls my calls etc.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup} from "@angular/forms";
import {TestService} from "./test.service";


class Customer {
  id : number;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  tel: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'sample-template',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html'})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  testForm: FormGroup;
  testForm2: FormGroup;
  public test: any;
  name: string = '';
  email: string = '';
  tel: string = '';
  public id: any;

  constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient, private fb: FormBuilder, private TestService: TestService) {}




  loadTasks(): void{
    this.TestService.getAllTests().subscribe(response => {this.test = response;
    console.log(this.test)})

  }

  ngOnInit() {

    let trainData = [];

    this.loadTasks();

    this.testForm = this.fb.group({
      testCd: 'Select'
    });

    this.testForm2 = this.fb.group({
      id: this.id,
      name: this.name,
      email: this.email,
      tel: this.tel
    })
  }

  changeDropdown(formControl: FormControl, option: string): void {
    formControl.patchValue(option);
    console.log(option);
  }

  submitForm(){
    let last:any = this.test[this.test.length-1];
    this.id = last.id+1;
    console.log(this.id);
    this.testForm2.value.id = this.id;
    console.log(this.testForm2.value);
    this.TestService.postTests(this.testForm2.value);
  }
}
```

And my html page which includes the following:

```
<label class="modelo-label">{{test?.testingTitle}}</label>
<form [formGroup]="testForm">
<div class="dropdown modelo-dropdown">
  <label for="testCd" class="modelo-label">Testing</label>
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" id="testCd" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">{{testForm.get('testCd').value}}</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu modelo-dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="testCd">
    <a class="dropdown-item" *ngFor="let tests of test?.trainData; let i = index" id="tests.name" (click)="changeDropdown(testForm.get('testCd'), tests.name)">{{tests.name}}</a>
  </div>
</div>

  <form [formGroup]="testForm2" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 group">
      <input type="text" id="name" formControlName="name" class="modelo-text-input"
             [ngClass]="{'ng-not-empty' : testForm2.get('name').value.length !== 0}">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 group">
      <input type="text" id="email" formControlName="email" class="modelo-text-input"
             [ngClass]="{'ng-not-empty' : testForm2.get('email').value.length !== 0}">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 group">
      <input type="text" id="tel" formControlName="tel" class="modelo-text-input"
             [ngClass]="{'ng-not-empty' : testForm2.get('tel').value.length !== 0}">
      <label for="tel">Telephone #</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1 group generateButton">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit Info</button>
  </div>
  </form>
```

My Question is, I'm have everything set up for a post and what I'm trying to do is post testForm2.value to the json but under "trainData":[{}] that's within the JSON. I'm able to do so if I just drop all other objects inside the json and have just the array after "customers":... What exactly am I missing? I'm actually confusing myself right now and I may be overthinking this by alot. The post I have currently in this code works if I have just the array after "customers":.... so instead of me passing object which is the testForm2.value what else do I need to do? I hope this makes sense.

Comment: What you are trying to do is pretty hard to understand.  When you valid the form  you want to add the test2Form2.value inside the  trainData array of the previously request JSON ? and  then update this one by doing a post

Comment: yes, I'm trying to explain the best I can sorry about the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some strange things in your code. First :

In you API

```
return this.http.get<Test[]>("http://localhost:3000/customers", {params}).pipe(map(res => res));
```

I think what you want to do here is : (the pipe is useless you dont use it and it's not an array)

```
return this.http.get<Test>("http://localhost:3000/customers",{params});
```

In your component you want to push the update trainData list

```
submitForm(){
    const lastTrainData = this.test.trainData[this.test.trainData.length-1];

    const newTrainData = this.testForm2.value;
    newTrainData.id = lastTrainData.id + 1;

    this.test.trainData.push(newTrainData);

    this.TestService.postTests(this.test);
  }
```

Comment: I was overthinking this, I made a slight adjustment to what you gave me but otherwise works like a beast! Thank you!

Comment: Ok with this, but your "type" are wrong. getAllTests should be named getCustomer no ? and return a Customer not a Test[]

Comment: No what I have is working perfectly (for now) it's pulling the data in correctly and I'm posting new data now thanks to your help on the posting call

Comment: because I'm calling other key/value's from the json not just trainData

Comment: yes but this.test is not concidered as an Array in your code, but in your Api you specify an array (but since you are doing on httpcall, at the runtime it's only a json object, not an array) else  this.test.trainData would fail  if this.test was an array